# Svelte export value but render it differently internally

Tags: svelte

I'm having a problem with my svelte Component.
I have something similar to this:

```js
export let date = new Date();
let internalDate = dateToInternalDate(date);
$: internalDate = dateToInternalDate(date);

//this wont work because of circular dependency:
$: date = internalDateToDate(internalDate);
```

I want to have my date value displayed as a formatted string internally. It should be bound to an input field like so:

```html
<!-- eg. formatted like: DD.MM.YYYY -->
<input type="text" bind:value={internalDate}>
```

My parent Component shall import this child like this:

```html
<MyDateComponent bind:date={myJsDateValue}>
```

I would like to be able to modify the date value from my child & my parent component.

What would be the most elegant way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can break the circular dependency by ensuring the *destination* variable doesn't appear in the reactive block. You can do this by keeping only the *source* variable to trigger the change in the reactive block, and extracting the *destination* variable into a function (hence, outside of the reactive block).

`MyDateComponent.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let date = new Date();
    
    let internalDate = ''
    
    const dateToInternalDate = x => {
        const d = new Date(x)
        return `${d.getFullYear()}-${String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')}-${String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}`
    }
    
    const internalDateToDate = x => {
        if (!/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/.test(x)) return
        const d = new Date(x)
        // bail out on invalid date
        if (isNaN(d.getTime())) return
        return d
    }
        
    const input = x => {
        internalDate = dateToInternalDate(x)
    }
    
    const output = x => {
        const v = internalDateToDate(x)
        if (v) date = v
    } 
    
    $: input(date)

    $: output(internalDate)
</script>

<!-- eg. formatted like: DD.MM.YYYY -->
<input type="text" bind:value={internalDate}>
```

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import MyDateComponent from './MyDateComponent.svelte'
    
    let date
</script>

<MyDateComponent bind:date />

<button on:click={() => {date = '2020-06-30'}}>2020-06-30</button>

<button on:click={() => {date = '2019-06-30'}}>2019-06-30</button>

<pre>Date: {date}</pre>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ef7910d3cb414abc92d973bb71fb5ed0?version=3.23.2)